# Get products based on user selected options in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want products that have ALL the options in the `IN` clause. Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT
    p.title, p.price FROM products AS p, product_options AS po
WHERE
    p.product_id = po.product_id
AND
    po.product_option_id IN (5,1,38,39)
GROUP BY
    p.product_id;
```

Comment: what is the problem with your current query?

Comment: @JW They want `ALL` options on the products. The current will give `OR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return the results that have all of those options, then you can use:

```
SELECT p.title, p.price 
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN product_options AS po
  ON p.product_id = po.product_id
WHERE po.product_option_id IN (5,1,38,39)
GROUP BY p.product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT po.product_option_id) = 4;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d04f/1)